# Visual Studio Code option is missing for Python

Tags: python

I installed Visual Studio Code v1.81.1 but do not see an option called "PYTHON FORMAT PROVIDER" like many course videos said should be in the settings.
I believe this may be why my code indentation does not get corrected by autopep8.
So where do I find this option or please reply why the improper indentation does not get corrected.

I tested with incorrect indentation and autopep8 didn't correct my test code.
I do see that the Visual Studio Code says I am using autocorrect8 in other parameters but am concerned why the "Python Formatting Provider" parameter is not there.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: possibly related or a duplicate of [Why does the VS Code Python extension (circa v2018.19) no longer provide support for several Python tools like linters and formatters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77283648/11107541)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear though I'm assuming you've not yet installed the python extension in VScode. I suggest you go to the extensions tab placed in the left-pane of VScode and install the [python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python), [pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) and the [python indent](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KevinRose.vsc-python-indent) by Kevin Rose. These extensions should solve your problem and make your journey a lot smoother. Happy coding!

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, but I double-checked my extensions, and Python, Pylance, and Python Indent are all installed (their status shows as UNINSTALL so I assume that means they are installed - correct?). Still having the "indent autocorrect" problem though the rest of my VC Code install seems OK.

Comment: okay then, press `ctrl+shift+p` on VSCODE and search for `convert indentation to tabs`.Press that while selecting the whole code. It should solve the indentation issue

Comment: I used the CONVERT INDENTATION TO TABS as suggested but it had no effect on correcting my indentation issue. I'm wondering if it has anything to do with my setting:  
                      "[python]": {
      "editor.formatOnType": true,
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8",
      "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
    "autopep8.showNotifications": "always"


I read that autopep8 was being deprecated and since I'm using the latest VSC 1.81.1 perhaps autopep8 is now useless?
If you're using VSC 1.81.1, perhaps you can share your JSON settings with me so I  can try them.

Comment: ```     "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "workbench.colorTheme": "βui - Nord",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.npy": "default"
    },
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/home/arrafi/miniconda3/bin/python"
} ```

Comment: Nothing you are using jumps out at me which would correct my issue, but thanks very much for sharing.

 Just to be sure I understand what auto-indent does:  I should expect if I define variable X in column 1 and then define variable Y on the next line in column 23, then as soon as I hit ENTER, Y should snap back to column 1 without me having to move it there. Correct?

Comment: Musabbir:  I found the answer to my auto-indent problem when using VS Code. It turns out all I had to do was click on the WORKSPACE TAB (not the USER tab) to access the "PYTHON > FORMATTING PROVIDER:" option, which allowed me to then select 'autopep8'.  Apparently, VSC moved it in version 1.81.1 to WORKSPACE and the YT video I was watching showed it under USER. Thanks very much for your suggestions and hanging in there with me.

Answer (score -1):

Well You could just install `Python` in VScode extension, it will automatically install `pylance` along with it, just to get you started. if you want more on formatting your code.

> Install Black Formatter by Microsoft in VScode extension or use pip ( preferred method ) https://pypi.org/project/black/

Comment: I already have the Python Indent (Kevin Rose) installed so it appears something is blocking/overriding my auto-indent request. Is Black Formatter better?